# What is role of field valueOffSet in AtomicReference getAndSet and other such methods

Tags: java, multithreading

I am studying non blocking algorithms. I realize that study of areas like volatile and Atomic* are crucial for this. So here is a question.
In **AtomicReference**, **compareAndSet** uses *unsafe.compareAndSwapObject(this, valueOffset, expect, update)*.
Another one, the infamous **lazySet** uses *unsafe.putOrderedObject(this, valueOffset, newValue);*.
I assume somewhere in these methods, a comparison of expect and update object will be done using "equals". Wonder how it is done atomically.. I guess, using CAS eventually, in some way.. and I guess, valueOffset has a role there.
Unfortunately, source code of Unsafe is not available.. and this code appears rather crucial to understand what in the world is valueOffset and what does it do. Anyone any idea please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you even trying to figure out how something that is so implementation specific works?

Anyway, did you look at where `valueOffset` was assigned?

```
private static final Unsafe unsafe = Unsafe.getUnsafe();
private static final long valueOffset;

static {
    try {
        valueOffset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset
            (AtomicReference.class.getDeclaredField("value"));
    } catch (Exception ex) { throw new Error(ex); }
}

private volatile V value;

public final boolean compareAndSet(V expect, V update) {
    return unsafe.compareAndSwapObject(this, valueOffset, expect, update);
}
```

It seems like `valueOffset` is the byte offset of field `value` from the beginning of the memory block pointed to by reference `this`.

---

As for whether you need to implement `equals()` in the value class, you don't.

`AtomicReference` is about the *reference*, not the object. The `compareAndSet()` method is about reference equality (`==`), not about the logical object equality implemented by `equals()`.

For example, the following code prints `false`, because the two `1` values are different object instances, even though they have the same logical "value".

```
AtomicReference r = new AtomicReference(new Integer(1));
boolean b = r.compareAndSet(new Integer(1), new Integer(2));
System.out.println(b);
```

The value of `r` did not get updated by `compareAndSet()`.

Comment: Sounds logical. It is important to know the answer. So from your logic it seems there is no need to implement equals in the 'value' inside AtomicReference.

Comment: @ApurvaSingh But the code is just delegating to `Unsafe`, so you still don't *know* the answer, since you don't know how `Unsafe` does it.

Comment: @ApurvaSingh No, you don't need to implement `equals()` in your value class, because this is about reference equality (`==`), not about the logical object equality implemented by `equals()`.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet @Andreas.. v helpful.. 
...and Eureka.. I got the source code of Unsafe (all native though) from open JDK.. so valueOffset is the position of the field 'value', and it is required because Unsafe deals only at byte level. Thanks
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/Unsafe.java

Comment: @Andreas I am unable to see magic behind `valueOffset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(AtomicReference.class.getDeclaredField("value"))` How can it be for `this`? Wouldnt value of `valueOffset` be same (irrespective of instance) once the AtomicReference class initializes for the first time?

Comment: @Archit It is the offset from the beginning of the object. It's a relative value which needs a reference point, i.e. the beginning of the object, to be useful. `this` is such as reference point.